# Is first character of varchar a string?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I achieve the below to show all rows where the first character of the ClientNumber is not a letter of the alphabet?

```
select * from Table
where Left(ClientNumber,1) <> A to Z
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
where left(clientNumber, 1) < 'A' or left(clientNumber, 1) > 'Z'
```

or:

```
where left(clientNumber, 1) not between 'A' and 'Z'
```

Do note, however, that the comparison will be tricky because of character case.  Assuming 1-byte characters, you might want:

```
where ascii(left(clientNumber, 1)) not between ascii('A') and ascii('Z')
```

EDIT:

If I wanted to use an index:

```
where clientNumber < 'A' or clientNumber > 'Z['
```

However, I'm not so sure an index is really useful in this case.

Comment: Did you mean `where upper(left(clientNumber, 1)) not between 'A' and 'Z'`, to cater for lowercase? I also like the `between` solution because it is portable (not all DBs support regex)

Comment: Placing ClientNumber in a function is going to make the query non-SARGEablie.

Answer (score 3):

You can use NOT LIKE:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table
WHERE ClientNumber NOT LIKE '[A-Za-z]%'
```

Comment: This is actually checking the first two characters, not just the first.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this...

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    dbo.MyTable mt
WHERE 
    mt.ClientNumber LIKE '[^a-Z]%'
```